# python - print out ports with their names

Tags: python, sockets, networking, port

I have the following code written in 2.7 python:

```
#...import stuff

remoteServer = raw_input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
remoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

print "Please wait, scanning remote Host", remoteServerIP

try:
    for port in xrange(1, 1024):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
        if result == 0:
            print "port {}:    open".format(port)
        sock.close

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "\nexiting..."
    sys.exit()
```

Output:

```
Enter a remote host to scan: www.myexamplesite.com
Please wait, scanning remote Host xxx.xxx.xx.xx
port 21:    open
port 22:    open
...
```

But the problem is that I also want to know which ports are used and for what they are used just like:

> ```
> #... as usual
> port 1 httpserver
> port 2 chat server
> ...
> ```

but this is only printing the ports from 1 to 1024
is there a function/way to do this?

Comment: IANA maintains the _[Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)_, but that doesn't guarantee that an application is not using a port in a non-standard way. For example, a host could be using the standard HTTP port 80 for something entirely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.getservbyport()` will translate port numbers into the service *expected* to be running on that port (via `/etc/services`), but won't actually communicate over the port to find out what is really running.

Comment: but i think most servers use the same ports for the same things right?